# Variable title not defined

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm getting the error `Variable title not defined` when executing a cypher query against our database. What is crazy to me is I am supplying that variable. Or at least I thought I was. The HTTP POST to cypher looks like this:

```
POST http://.../db/data/cypher HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: Basic ...
User-Agent: ...
X-Stream: true
Content-Length: 955
Host: ...

{
  "query": "MATCH (n:Event {id: {id}}) SET title = {title}, location = {location}, shortDescription = {shortDescription}, longDescription = {longDescription}, eventDates = {eventDates}, puchaseUrl = {purchaseUrl}, infoUrl = {infoUrl}, images = {images} RETURN n",
  "params": {
    "title": "Our First Event",    <<==== title supplied here
    "location": "The location",
    "shortDescription": "The short description.",
    "longDescription": "The long description is longer.",
    "eventDates": [
      {
        "date": "2016-09-01T12:00:00",
        "duration": 120,
        "Id": 0
      },
      {
        "date": "2016-09-02T14:00:00",
        "duration": 120,
        "Id": 0
      }
    ],
    "purchaseUrl": null,
    "infoUrl": null,
    "images": [
      {
        "url": "http://sandwichevents.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/many-people-music-event-concert-awesome.jpg",
        "name": "event9_image1.jpg",
        "altText": "Something here.",
        "isDefault": false,
        "Id": 0
      },
      {
        "url": "http://www.event360.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/1.full-size-promo-62sm.jpg",
        "name": "event9_image2.jpg",
        "altText": "Something else here.",
        "isDefault": true,
        "Id": 0
      }
    ],
    "Id": 9
  }
}
```

Can somebody direct me as to what I did wrong here?

**Update:** it even fails if you set `"eventDates"` and `"images"` to `null`; thus leaving out any complex data structures as children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that none of the properties you're trying to set are being treated as properties, they're being treated as variables, and none of those variables exist; `title` is only showing up because it's the first one that Cypher encounters, but every one of them would throw this same error if the error didn't halt their evaluation.

When setting properties, prefix with the variable of the containing node (`SET n.title = {title}`, and so on).